Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Signing
Is it possible to sign Ubuntu VM Images?
I am using EC2 for my environment.
My team needs signed VMs for maintaining and ensuring integrity.
I am aware of Container signing and I have also worked on it using cosign.
But I am not aware and sure whether signing can be applied to VM as well.
If yes then it will be great if someone can provide me list of tools (paid/opensource) and approach to achieve the same.

It's possible to sign lots of things. For a "VM" the signing can only really apply to the VM image (or AMI, or VMDK) which is something outside of the VM itself - so the fact the Ubuntu is installed on the VM is irrelevant. AFAIK AWS has no mechanism for signing or validating signatures on VMs. It can implement encrypted VMs - but that's not what you asked for.
You'd need to build the capability into your deployment tooling.
Its odd that you are so concerned about the security of your VMs but are using a old distribution that will be EOL soon.
